# Is there any Ruby project for backup?

Tags: ruby, backup

I have some rails projects and mysql database in the server, i need to backup them every 1-2 days. I would like to do backup with Ruby, who can give me some advice? thanks!

Comment: What OS? And, why do you want to use Ruby? There are some excellent tools out there that are in other languages or that are compiled for speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of links below which can help you taking your Rails application backup

http://johntopley.com/2009/09/14/back-up-your-rails-application-to-the-cloud

http://storecrowd.com/blog/rails-backups/

http://backupmyapp.com/ (If you are willing to pay)

Answer (score 4):

Consider - https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup

Backupmyapp.com failed for me when i gave it a shot sometime ago.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/evgenyneu/siba-source-mysql

MySQL backup and restore tool built in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem that Ruby should solve.

If you need to do it every 1-2 days, create a cron job that runs a backup script that calls a tool such as `mysqldump` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the idea of using Ruby makes sense, in a lot of ways.

1. For an automated backup process, speed isn't that big an issue.
2. For access to a database, you can still invoke MySQL (and it's a good idea to do so)
3. But Ruby's DSL capabilities invite the construction of "backup language" that can be used to write a backup script that can, for example, copy the same structure to multiple locations, at a time you specify, all in a way that is both human-readable and executable. A script written with a reasonable Domain-Specific Language would be both easy to read and easy to modify later.

That is Ruby's strength (and the reason I'm here :__) As I contemplate just such a DSL, I'm trying to see if anyone has beaten me to it. (Surprisingly, nothing has immediately leaped out of the bushes...)